# How to simulate a pwm semnal python script

Tags: python, scripting, signals, microcontroller, pwm

I need to Simulate Saw-Tooth voltage (4.5 - 0.5V) a total of 30 times . And I don't know how to do it only with python scripts without special library or something. I have this function, but how I do it to work?

```
def PWM(t, frequency, dutyCycle):

    #period = 1 / frequency
    #pt = tt / period
    pt = tt * frequency # "period" time, where 1 unit is 1 period on the "real" time stamp.
    tc = pt - trunc(pt) # cycle time within 1 period. 0..1.
    return 1 if tc < dutyCycle else 0 # where 1 means on and 0 means off
```

Comment: Yes, I think is good. I just need to simulate the Saw-Tooth on a micro, and monitor a variable what behavier it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but here you can see a function that given a time `t` returns the amplitude of a saw-tooth signal with a certain frequency and dutyCycle.

The signal is normalized, you can shift the values if you need

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def SawTooth(t, frequency, dutyCycle):
    period = 1 / frequency
    t_on = period * dutyCycle
    t_off = period - t_on
    
    # the modulo will return the remainder of time inside the current period
    remainder = t % period
    if remainder > t_on:
        return 0
    else:
        return remainder / t_on

frequency = 50
dutyCycle = 0.5
samplingFreq = 10000
timeDuration = 0.1
# Generate 100ms of data with a sampling freq of 10k
t_ms = np.linspace(0, time_duration*1000, samplingFreq*timeDuration)
y = []
for t in t_ms:
    y.append(SawTooth(t/1000, frequency, dutyCycle))

plt.plot(t_ms,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: btw I'm assuming that this is not what the OP wants since they mention PWM a couple of times.

Comment: well, a PWM signal is a square signal where you modulate the dutyCycle. This is very similar, but instead of square is  saw-tooth. Technically is not a pwm, but is very easily adaptable to transform it into a pwm signal. Just return 1 instead of `remainder / t_on`

Comment: The other difference is that a PWM signal has to be a much higher frequency than the final output waveform.

Comment: Yes, but the final waveform will be generated when applying a carrier and using this as the modulation. That's why dutyCycle is a parameter, you can change it at every call. Depending on the application the OP might want one thing or another, it's unclear. This answer generates what you see and might or might not answer the original question.

Comment: And how I import this library? import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

Comment: if you have matplotlib installed just import it as I do in my code. But matplotlib is only for visualization, you don't actually need it at all for the function